# Assign Text Separated Comma to (IN SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like assign this text separated comma to IN. Have you got idea how to do it?

```
DECLARE @TESTTEXT varchar(200)

SET @TESTTEXT = '101,103,104'

SELECT 1 WHERE '101' IN (@TESTTEXT)
```

[image]

Comment: Articles worth reading are [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @TESTTEXT varchar(200)
SET @TESTTEXT = '101,103,104'

exec('SELECT 1 WHERE ''101'' IN ( ' + @TESTTEXT + ')')
```

Comment: Thanks I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use LIKE:

```
select 1 where ',' || @TESTTEXT || ',' like '%,101,%'
```

The extra commas are there to handle first and last item in list.

`||` is ANSI SQL for `concat`, perhaps tsql has other notation?

Comment: I gave you point. Thanks for your answer and time.